# ERROR on VF PAGE :it should only display the Account Name

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, standardcontroller

Can any one help me out with this Error on Vf page.Any help is very much appreciated.[image]

**When i test in my Sandbox ,it just display the a/c name .Similarly when i check in Production for one of the record i do get the a/c name + another name .**

Here is My VF page Code :

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" renderAs="pdf" applyhtmltag="false" showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false" extensions="InvoiceController">
<head>
    <style>

    @page {
        margin: 1px 50px 225px 50px; 
        size:A4;
        Padding-top:30px;

        @top-center { 
                content : element(header);
             }

        @bottom-center {
                content : element(footer);
                height:200px;
                padding-top:10px;
             }
    } 
    body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; }
    .companyName { font: bold 30px; color: red; }  
    table {width:100%; border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; border-width: 1px; border-color:#C0C0C0;border-style:solid;} 
    .header-table-data { border-width: 1px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#FFFFFF;
                         color:Black; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana;
                         text-align:center;}
    .header-table-heading {border-width: 1px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#C0C0C0; 
                           font-weight:bold;color:Black; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana;
                           text-align:center;}
    .header-data { border-width: 0px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#FFFFFF;
                   color:Black; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana;text-align:left; padding-right: 10px;}

    .header-heading {border-width: 0px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid; 
                     font-weight:bold;color:Black; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana;
                     text-align:left;}
</style>

</head>
<body> 

 <table>
    <tr>
        <td><img style="WIDTH:25%; HEIGHT: 25%" src='{!URLFOR($Resource.Bridgelux_New_Logo)}' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <br/>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Commercial Invoice</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table><br/>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0" >
    <tr>
       <!--- <td border="0" bgcolor="Silver">Sold To</td>-->
        <td bgcolor="Silver">Ship To:</td>
        <td bgcolor="Silver">Ship From</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!--<td style="border-width: 0px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#FFFFFF;" align="left" width="10%">
            <f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">-->
                <!-- Code starts here ********************************************************* -->
                <!-- {!showaddressonVf} -->
                <!--<apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.account.Name}"></apex:outputText><br/>-->
                <!-- Added by Sumit -->
                <!--<apex:outputText value=" {!all}" escape="false"></apex:outputText>-->
                <!--     -----------   -->
                <!--<br />
            </f>
        </td> -->     
        <td style="border-width: 0px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#FFFFFF;" align="left" width="10%">
        <f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">
            <!-- Code starts here ********************************************************* -->
            <!-- Added below line by KiranmaiKosaraju. To show Ship To Account Name If diff from Account Name or else show Account Name -->
            <apex:outputText value="{!IF ((opportunity.Ship_To_Account_Name__c = NULL),  opportunity.account.Name,opportunity.Ship_To_Account_Name__c)}"></apex:outputText><br /> 
            <!--<apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.account.Name}"></apex:outputText><br /> -->
            <!-- Added by Sumit -->
            <apex:outputText value=" {!all}" escape="false"></apex:outputText>
            <!--     -----------   -->
            <br />  
        </f>
        </td>
        <td style="border-width: 0px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#FFFFFF;" align="left" width="10%">
        <f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">
            Bridgelux Inc. C/O JSI Logistics (HK) Ltd.<br/>
            16/F Tsuen Wan International Center,<br/>
            68 Wang Lung Street, Tsuen Wan,<br/>
            Hong Kong<br/>
            Tel: (852) 3761 7080<br/>
            Fax: (852) 2750 0721<br/>
        </f>
        <f style="color:Blue; font-size:12px; font-family:Tahoma;"> Email:Info@bridgelux.com</f>
        <f style="color:Blue; font-size:10px; font-family:Trebuchet MS;"><br/> </f>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table> 

 <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="100%" >
    <tr>
         <td class="header-heading">
            Ship Date:
         </td>
         <td class="header-data">
            <apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Sys_today_s_date__c}"></apex:outputText><br/>
         </td>
         <td class="header-heading">
            Special Instructions:
         </td>
         <td class="header-data">                
            <apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Special_Instructions__c}"></apex:outputText>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table> 

<table>
    <tr border="0">
        <td class="header-table-heading">CI Invoice Id</td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">Ship Date<b/></td>
        <!---<td class="header-table-heading">Sales Order#</td>-->
        <td class="header-table-heading">Opportunity Name</td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">Order Date</td>
        <!--<td class="header-table-heading">Customer#</td>-->
        <td class="header-table-heading">Customer Name</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Salesorder_number__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
        <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Sys_today_s_date__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
        <!--<td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Salesorder_number__c}"></apex:outputText></td>-->
         <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Name}"></apex:outputText></td>
         <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Sys_createddate__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
         <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.account.Name}"></apex:outputText></td>
        <!--<td class="header-table-data">{!Opportunity.account.Ebs_Customer_number__c}</td>-->
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table >
    <tr>
        <td class="header-table-heading">LN</td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">Item</td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">Customer Item #<b/></td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">COO</td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">ECCN #</td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">UOM</td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">Unit Price</td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">Quantity</td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">Extension</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="header-table-heading"></td>
        <td colspan="8" style="text-align:left"  class="header-table-heading">Description</td>
    </tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!appointmentList}" var="line">
    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!if(line.pick==true, true, false)}">

    <tr>         
        <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!line.LineNumber}"></apex:outputText></td>
        <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!line.productname}"></apex:outputText></td>
        <td class="header-table-data"></td>
        <td class="header-table-data"></td>
        <td class="header-table-data">8541.40.2000</td>
        <td class="header-table-data">EA</td>
        <td class="header-table-data">$1</td>
        <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputtext value="{!line.quantity}"></apex:outputtext></td>
        <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!line.extension}"></apex:outputText></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="header-table-data"></td>

        <td colspan="8" style="text-align:left" class="header-table-data"><b>Scheduled Ship Date:</b>
                    <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
                            <apex:param value="{!line.Scheduledshipdate}"/>
                    </apex:outputText> </td>
    </tr>
    </apex:outputPanel>    
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
<br/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="header-table-heading">Gross Weight</td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">Net Weight</td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">Shipped Via</td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">Tracking #</td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">Payment Terms</td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">Incoterms </td>
        <td class="header-table-heading">Currency </td>
        <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-heading">Sub Total <br/>Shipping Charges</td>
        <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Pick_Total__c}"></apex:outputText>
             <br/><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Shipping_Charges__c}"></apex:outputText><br/></td>

    </tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!appointmentList1}" var="line1">
    </apex:repeat>
    <tr>
        <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Gross_Weight__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
        <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Net_weight__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
        <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Shipped_Via__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
        <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Bill_of_Lading__c}"> </apex:outputText></td>
        <td class="header-table-data">Net 30</td>
        <td class="header-table-data">EXW</td>
        <td class="header-table-data">USD</td>
        <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-heading"> Total Amount Due</td>
        <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Pick_Total__c + opportunity.Shipping_Charges__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Class :

```
public with sharing class InvoiceController {
           List<wrapperClass> appointmentList {get;set;}
           List<wrapperClass> appointmentList1 {get;set;} 
           public list<string> addaress{get;set;}
           public string address1{get;set;}
           public string address2{get;set;}
           public string address3{get;set;}
           public string address4{get;set;}
           public string address5{get;set;}
           public string address6{get;set;}
           public string address7{get;set;}
           public  String showaddressonVf{get;set;}
           public string wholeaddress{get;set;}
   //Added by sumit
               List<String> stringList;
               public String all{get;set;}
           //------------
   public InvoiceController(){
   list<opportunity> op=[select id,Shipment_Info__c
   from opportunity where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];
    //opportunity op=[select id,Shipment_Info__c from opportunity where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];
       //---------------------Added by sumit----------------------
       stringList= new List<String>(); 
       if(op.size()>0)
       if(op[0].Shipment_Info__c!=NULL && op[0].Shipment_Info__c!=''){
           List<String> stringList=(op[0].Shipment_Info__c).split(',');
               for(integer i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
                   all=all+stringList[i]+'<br/>';
               }

           all=all.remove('null');      
        }
      //------------------------------------------------------------
   }
       public Id OppId{get;set;}


       public InvoiceController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
       oppId=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');
   }
               public List<wrapperClass> getappointmentList (){
               wrapperClass tempObj ;
               tempObj = new wrapperClass();
               List<wrapperClass> aReList = new List<wrapperClass>(); 
           List<Opportunity> opp=[select id,Name,AccountId from Opportunity where id=:oppid limit 1];
           List<opportunity> Opp1=[select id,name,CreatedDate from opportunity where id=:oppid];
           //Opportunity opp1=[select id,Name,AccountId from Opportunity where id=:oppid limit 1];
           //Opportunity Opp=[select id,name,CreatedDate from opportunity where id=:oppid ];
                          List<OpportunityLineItem> OPplineitem= [SELECT OpportunityId,Quantity,PricebookEntry.Product2.Name,Sys_total_Amount__c,LN__c,Extension__c,ListPrice
                          ,Pick__c,Schedule_Ship_date__c
                          FROM OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId=:oppId]; 
                          system.debug('HHHHHHHHHH'+OPplineitem.size());


               for(integer i=0; i < OPplineitem.size(); i++)
               {
                 tempObj = new wrapperClass();
                 tempObj.productname= OPplineitem[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name;
                 tempObj.quantity=OPplineitem[i].Quantity;
                 tempObj.totalamount=OPplineitem[i].Sys_total_Amount__c;
                 tempObj.unitprice=OPplineitem[i].ListPrice;
                 tempobj.extension=OPplineitem[i].Extension__c;
                 tempobj.LineNumber=OPplineitem[i].LN__c;
                 tempobj.Pick= OPplineitem[i].Pick__c;
                 tempobj.ScheduledShipDate = Opplineitem[i].schedule_ship_date__c;

                 if(tempobj!=null){
                    aReList.add(tempObj);
                 }
                }
       return aReList;
     }



       public List<wrapperClass> getappointmentList1 (){
           wrapperClass tempObj1 ; 
           List<wrapperClass> aReList1 = new List<wrapperClass>();
                   List<Opportunity> opp=[select id,Name,AccountId,Shipment_Info__c,
                    Shipping_Address_Line1__c,
                        Shipping_Address_Line2__c,
                        Shipping_Address_Line3__c,
                        Shipping_City__c,
                        Shipping_State_Province__c,
                        Shipping_Zipcode__c,
                        Shipping_Country__c  
                        from Opportunity where id=:oppid];
           for(integer i=0; i < opp.size(); i++)
           {
             tempObj1 = new wrapperClass();
             tempObj1.billingAddress= opp[i].Shipment_Info__c;
                               }
             aReList1.add(tempObj1);        

             /* Below code commented by Kiranmai as Shipment Info field is split into multiple fields

             //------- Added by Sumit-----------  
             stringList= new List<String>(); 

             if(aReList1[0].billingAddress!=NULL && aReList1[0].billingAddress!=''){
                List<String> stringList=(aReList1[0].billingAddress).split(',');
                for(integer i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
                   all=all+stringList[i]+'<br/>';
                }
             } */

             all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line1__c + '<br/>';
             if(opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line2__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line2__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line2__c + '<br/>';
             }

             if(opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line3__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line3__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line3__c + '<br/>';
             } 

             if(opp[0].Shipping_City__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_City__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_City__c + '<br/>';
             }

             if(opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c + '<br/>';
             }  

             if(opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c + '<br/>';
             }

             if(opp[0].Shipping_Country__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Country__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Country__c + '<br/>';
             }
            /* all = all + opp[0].Shipping_City__c + ', '+opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c + ' - ' + opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c + '<br/>';
             all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Country__c + '<br/>';*/

             all=all.remove('null');

                /*-----------------------------------*/ 
      return aReList1;  
   }
           public class wrapperClass{
           public String productname{get;set;}
           public Decimal Quantity{get;set;}
           public Decimal totalamount{get;set;}                            
           public Decimal unitprice{get;set;}
           public date todaysdate{get;set;}
           public decimal extension{get;set;}
           public string LineNumber{get;set;}
           public string billingAddress{get;set;}
           public string splittedaddress{get;set;}
           public string wholeaddress{get;set;}
           public boolean Pick{get;set;}
           public date ScheduledShipDate{get;set;}
           public wrapperClass(){}                
       }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The second name is coming from your `<apex:outputText value=" {!all}" escape="false"></apex:outputText>` directly below.  The page has Opportunity as the standard controller, however in your constructor you are fetching the same data and placing it into `all`.

Comment: :Thanks for ur reply .I didnt get u completely .Can u please explain me in detail.I do have other records in which it just displays  the Account Name as per the required o/p.Only this record does not give the o/p as per the required.

Answer (score -1):

@ScottW:In the First Line :it is the Customer Name and the Second line :is the Shipping Address Line 1.

Comment: Yes @Nikki, Shipping address is appearing on the second line. So the case is now clear, if you wanna display only account, comment-out the entire logic where you're appending text  into "all" .